# Firebase REST API: How to fetch data by priority like startAt/endAt in JS?

Tags: firebase

I need to fetch my data by a priority range, like you can with startAt/endAt in the JS, but in REST. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is now possible with the beta Queries API.

As per https://www.firebase.com/docs/beta/queries/rest.html:

> The startAt parameter accepts whatever type you specify in orderBy.
>   This query finds all dinosaurs at least 3 meters tall.
>
> ```
> curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="height"&startAt=3'
> ```
>
> And this query finds all dinosaurs starting with Stegosaurus.
>
> ```
> curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="stegosaurus"'
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't yet possible with the REST API.

You can, however, run on Node.js client on your own server, and query your data in that way:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/nodejs-quickstart.html

Comment: ARGH. How is it that this is STILL not possible? I'm having HUGE latency issues with a Flash/Flex module trying to interface with Firebase because the overall node gets huge after a lot of messages are posted to it. The Flash has to fetch the entire json object for the node and parse it. If you'd add the priority option we could actually make this thing work. Any idea how long before this is added?

Comment: @AndrewChristensen try archiving old data to improve latency. Keep the current records you want to fetch in a new path. Queries are helpful but not going to resolve bulky data. But do hang in there. I think REST will have limit/startAt/endAt within a week or two (as soon as the release pushes live and the docs are updated).

Comment: Is this still a planned update to the REST service this month?