# Paginating Firebase data through the REST API

Tags: rest, pagination, firebase

I see that you can paginate Firebase data through the JS interface with WebSocket, but there's nothing listed with REST.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebase REST API: How to fetch data by priority like startAt/endAt in JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671000/firebase-rest-api-how-to-fetch-data-by-priority-like-startat-endat-in-js)