# Firebase filter records using the REST API (active vs inactive)

Tags: firebase

My company is considering using Firebase for a particular project dealing with massive dynamic forms. There have been some flags raised with the Firebase service that I would like to remove before we start.

First off I've read through the blog posts here:

https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html

https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html

The basic queries they outline are pretty self explanatory and I believe will be enough for the projects reporting inquiries, however is this only available for the Web API? Is there a way to search or get filtered data from Firebase from the REST API or is it up to the developers here to filter through a bunch of data?

My problem stems from a couple models that need to show reports based off some of the data we plan to offload to Firebase.

For example:

```
Site (Hosted internally)
  activeSurveyId: *firebase survey id*

Survey (Hosted through Firebase)
  siteId: *site this firebase survey belongs to*
  status: "In Progress"
  ...
```

If I just wanted the survey for a site that's simple, however if i wanted to compile a report of all Survey's with the status of "In Progress" is there a simple way to do that from the REST API?

I'd love to use this product as it's quite slick. We just need to make sure it meets our requirements without doing a bunch of extra work on our end for filtering / searching.

Comment: Related (though somewhat old and hopefully outdated): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671000/firebase-rest-api-how-to-fetch-data-by-priority-like-startat-endat-in-js

Comment: The simplest option would be to simply store surveys that are in progress in one path, and those that are completed in another path.

Comment: this my be helpful for you https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html

Comment: Kato's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is the case with a lot of questions about querying in Firebase (and other noSql databases), the answer is to avoid the need to make complex queries. Structure your data to reduce or eliminate the need for queries.

Firebase has a blog entry about this, [Denormalizing Your Data is Normal](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html), which I recommend you read.

To resolve your specific issue, your best bet is to store the surveys that are in progress in a different root node than those that are completed. Your structure might look something like this:

```
"surveys": {
    "in-progress": {
        "-JTICjjZfm8faeMo11FF": { ... data for one survey ... },
        ... 
     }
    "completed": {
        "-JTICdawddwMo11DWCwd": { ... data for one survey ... },
        ... 
     }
}
```