# Firebase searching for records via REST

Tags: api, rest, firebase

I have been getting to grips with the Firebase REST API, but unfortunately can't seem to find a way to search for a record via name, email etc. I see that this may be possible using the JS interface.

Can you tell me if there is a way to do this via REST?

Comment: This is not currently possible via the REST API. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671000/firebase-rest-api-how-to-fetch-data-by-priority-like-startat-endat-in-js. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510541/firebase-filter-records-using-the-rest-api-active-vs-inactive?lq=1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Frank, it seems NodeJS is the only way to go.